# How to handle vue event using javascript code?

Tags: vue.js, events

I want to create a custom vue component using js code.

I can create the component using js code and add it to the DOM, but I don't know how to use js code to handle the event.

```
import listitem from './listitem'
var ItemClass = Vue.extend(listitem);
var component = new ItemClass();
component.$mount();
this.$refs.listmain.appendChild(component.$el);
```

I want to fulfill this.

```
<div ref="listmain">
    <listitem @eventname="handleevent"></listitem>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by reading the API document.

```
import listitem from './listitem'
var ItemClass = Vue.extend(listitem);
var component = new ItemClass();
component.$on('eventname', function(msg) {

})
component.$mount();
this.$refs.listmain.appendChild(component.$el);
```